# Best alternative for password_hash in PHP 5.3.27?

Tags: php, security, encryption, php-password-hash

I've been searching around the internet for the best option to encrypt passwords for databases. I've found that `password_hash()` is the best option, but then I saw that it is only for PHP 5.5+. Apparently my host has version 5.3.27. And I've been searching for the best alternative but couldn't find anything good.

Comment: If you read the doc pages for [password_hash()](http://prototype.php.net/function.password-hash), you'll find the link to this [userland implementation](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat)

Comment: @MarkBaker, just out of curiosity, why do some users put answers in comments, and not as answers? :)

Comment: @Matthew - if my answer to a question would fit within the 140-character limitation of a tweet, I'll generally just answer as a comment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The library below gives you password_hash for php < 5.5

https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat.git

Comment: that library is for 5.3.7 and higher i have 5.3.27

Comment: @Baspetersnl: 5.3.27 > 5.3.7, so this should work for you `:)`