# Php header not working on server?

Tags: php, mysql

**edit : I've checked all the permissions and they where all set at 755 so that shouldn't be the problem**

I've made a script which was working. But then I put files in different folders and for some reason `header();` isn't working anymore

This is what my folders look like :

[image]

You have the `index.php` form which looks like this :

```
<form action='../login.php' method="post">

 Gebruikersnaam:<br>
 <input type="text"  name="username" placeholder="Je leerlingnummer"  required/><br>
 wachtwoord:<br>
 <input type="password"  name="password" placeholder="Je wachtwoord" required/><br>
 <div class="g-recaptcha"  data-sitekey="6LeLbhgUAAAAAKUTJmf9CeIB2JbgsG3C0ftJsJAp"></div>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" class="groottext" value="inloggen" />
</form>
```

The login script was working before but since I've put the files inside a specific folder it doesn't redirect anymore it keeps the page at `login.php` which looks like this :

```
if ($rows['authlvl'] == '1') {
    header('location: leerling/repairs.php'); //User1 
    session_register("username");
    session_register("password");

} else
if ($rows['authlvl'] == '2') {
    header('location: admin/lloverzicht.php'); //User2 
    session_register("username");
    session_register("password");

} else
if ($rows['authlvl'] == '3') {
    header('location: admin/overzicht.php'); //user 3 
    session_register("username");
    session_register("password");

} else {

    echo "not authorised";
}

?>
```

There's some other code in `login.php` which is working because I have tested it, the only thing that doesn't work is the redirecting :

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ini_set('display_errors', 1);
 <?php include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/var/www/includes/dbconnect.php' ); ?>
 $tbl_name="users"; 

 $username=$_POST['username'];  
 $password=$_POST['password']; 



 $username = stripslashes($username);
 $password = stripslashes($password);


 $password = md5($password);

 $sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE username='$username' and   password='$password'";
 $result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

 $rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);



 if ($rows['authlvl'] == '1') {
 header('location: leerling/repairs.php' ); //User1 
 session_start("username");
 session_start("password");

 }
 else
 if ($rows['authlvl'] == '2') {
 header('location: admin/lloverzicht.php'); //User2 
 session_start("username");
 session_start("password"); 

 } 
 else
 if ($rows['authlvl'] == '3') {
 header('location: admin/overzicht.php'); //user 3 
 session_start("username");
 session_start("password"); 

 } 

 else
 { 

 echo "je hebt geen toegang tot deze pagina";
}

?>
```

The page it redirects to

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Adatum Reparatie Syteem</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <?php include "../includes/header2.php"; ?>
  <div id="overzichtcontainer">
    <h1> Reparatie aanmaken </h1>
    <div id="formdiv">
      <form action="insert1.php" method="post">
        Leerlingnummer:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="leerlingnummer" required placeholder="Voer hier  het leerlingnummer in" />
        <br> E-mailadres:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="emailadres" required placeholder="Voer hier het e-mail adres van de leerling in" />
        <br>
        <br> 2e e-mailadres:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="emailadres2" required placeholder="Voer hier het e-mailadres van de ouder/verzorger in" />
        <br>
        <br> Telefoonnummer:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="telnr" required placeholder="Voer hier het   telefoonnummer in waarop u bereikbaar bent" />
        <br>
        <br> Serienummer:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="serienummer" required placeholder="Het serienummer van het ingenomen Device" />
        <br>
        <br> Serienummer (leen Device):
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="serienummer2" required placeholder="Het serienummer van het uitgegeven Device" />
        <br>
        <br> Schermcode:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="schermcode" required placeholder="De code om het scherm te ontgrendelen" />
        <br>
        <br> Schade / Reparatie:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="schade" required placeholder="Omschrijving schade" />
        <br>
        <br> Waterschade:
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="water" value="nee" checked/>Nee
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="water" value="ja" />ja
        <br>
        <br> Valschade:
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="val" value="nee" checked/>Nee
        <br>
        <input type="radio" name="val" value="ja" />ja
        <br>
        <br> Aankoopdatum Device:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="date" required placeholder="dd-mm-yy" />
        <br>
        <br> Leverancier Device:
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="levdevice" required placeholder="Waar is het Device gekocht" />
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" class="groottext" value="Reparatie indienen" />
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: add the top of your code add `ob_start();` or add `exit()` after redirect

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile so exit() after the final echo ?

Comment: No, after `header()`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i've tried ob_start() and exit() after header() and it still doesn't work

Comment: it just stays there? no errors? u have error reporting enabled?

Comment: it just goes to login.php. i have error reporting on .

Comment: maybe these pages : `repairs.php` `lloverzicht.php` `overzicht.php`  they have a redirect that also redirects them back to login hence u stucked there, **redirect loop**

Comment: its not a redirect loop i've double checked it

Comment: can you show your full login page

Comment: I don't see any update the code still the same, your code starts wit `if`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile you should be able to see it now

Comment: someone just edited the post and the full page is gone now

Comment: which php version are u using? `session_register` function has been **DEPRECATED** as of PHP 5.3.0 and **REMOVED** as of PHP 5.4.0.

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i've changed it to session_start(); and reuploaded the code again

Comment: then change these `session_register("username");
 session_register("password");` to `$_session['username'] = $row['username']` its not a good idea to store password in a session var
`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile yes i've done just that but it still doesnt fix my problem

Comment: Please add the latest login.php and also add one of the pages u redirecting to

Comment: whats on `header2.php?`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile <?php
echo'
<ul class="topnav">
<li><a class="active" href="../index.php">Adatum / Isendoorn</a></li>
<li><a href="repairs.php">Reparatie invoeren</a></li>
<li class="right"><a href="overzicht.php">Overzicht</a></li>
</ul>';
?>

Comment: this is wrong `session_start("password");`

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile the problem doesnt have anything to do with the session because it works without it

Comment: *the problem doesnt have anything to do with the session because it works without it*  you have your answer then

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile it still doesnt work but it should work even without the session

Comment: there's an error here : `<?php include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/var/www/includes/dbconnect.php' ); ?>` You opened a php tag inside a php tag then closed the php tag the code below this line is not inside <?php

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile i've got it on 1 line now but its still not working.

Comment: always update with the latest code u have

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile it is updated

Comment: I don't see any update

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile its on the same page for me...

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I agree completely with all of your comments. I think you should "collect" your comments into an answer (you can future update with an actual answer, dependant on data given by the OP). I'd +1 you. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The solution to your issue is given from the very adept comments made by **Masivuye Cokile** and I'm not going to take the piss by copying his comments and getting a tick or +1.

But there's so many other issues with your code, I can't resist telling you these issues so you know them, can see them, and can work to resolve them.

Sorry, but the code shown just reeks of 2006.

- You shuold ***not*** be using `md5` for passwords, use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) even [pre-PHP 5.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20229058/best-alternative-for-password-hash-in-php-5-3-27).
- You should ***not*** be using `stripslashes` or manual variable concatentation for SQL generation. Use Paramaterised queries. Google it.
- You ***MUST*** properly escape user data, `stripslashes` is *NOT* good enough. as a very bare minimum you should be using [`mysqli_real_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).
- `session_register` ***is deprecated***. Stop using it. Instead use the `$_SESSION` superglobal value.
- After your `header` redirects to another page you should force the PHP script to end *as soon as possible* after this instruction.

  PHP will continue to process the page and so the first header relocation can then be overwritten by a second `header`

  ```
   header("Location: indexA.php");
   header("Location: indexB.php");
   //// here the page indexB.php will always be loaded.
   // because after calling the indexA.php the script needs 
   // to be stopped with exit or die(); commands.
  ```
- `$rows['authlvl'] == '2'` This is inefficient. PHP can type juggle so you can simply compare it as a number (int) rather than forcing it to being a string. Instead: `$rows['authlvl'] == 2`.
- Your code here will cause syntax errors:

  ```
       <?php
       error_reporting(E_ALL);
       <?php include( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/var/www/includes/dbconnect.php' ); ?>
  ```

  For two reasons:

  - 1 You have a PHP opening tag within another PHP opening tag:

    ```
      <?php 

      <?php
    ```

  This is invalid. Remove the internal opening and closing tags.
  And

  - 2 It looks very much like `SERVER['document_root'] == /var/www/includes/dbconnect.php` The Server document root value will go to the base of your Public HTML area of your server, tyically this will be the `/www/` folder, so you're URL
    `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/var/www/` seems to me very likely to be an invalid folder structure value.

    Try to use `print_r($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);` and then adjust your `/var/www/...` to fit what this tells you.

Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

It is important to notice that header() must be called before any actual output is sent (In PHP 4 and later, you can use output buffering to solve this problem).

just Check your php file..
Maybe you have printed out some text before the header() function, maybe a blank space.

Check the first line of login.php file does not have a blank space, something like this:

```
--- Blank space ---
<?php
```

if exist then change it to

```
<?php
```

Comment: why must he use js?

Comment: still does not explain why he should use js instead of `header()`

Comment: I was having the same problem that time  js redirection helped me. So i thought it will help him.